# c# open serial port created by socat

Tags: virtual-serial-port, socat

Create two virtual serial ports

```
socat  -d -d -d  PTY,b115200,raw,echo=0,crnl,link=/home/user/ttyS110 PTY,b115200,raw,echo=0,crnl,link=/home/user/ttyS111
```

cat /home/user/ttyS110
echo "hello" > /home/user/ttyS111
Works!

Try open:

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace qqq
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            SerialPort fSerialPort = new SerialPort();

            fSerialPort.PortName = "/home/user/ttyS111";

            fSerialPort.BaudRate = 115200;
            fSerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
            fSerialPort.DataBits = 8;
            fSerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            fSerialPort.ReadTimeout = 500;
            fSerialPort.WriteTimeout = 500;

            try
            {
                fSerialPort.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Open port");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Open port ERROR! " + e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Catch exception "Invalid argument".

How open virtual port from c# (Mono)?

Answer (score 1):

It would seem this has something to do with socat not emulating a serial port correctly.  All I could find that was of help was the info below, which relates to a USB to Serial adapter, but I'm guessing socat is behaving the same way.

> When opening the serial port, System.IO.Ports.SerialPort indirectly
>   calls SetSignal, which calls the TIOCMGET ioctl, which, as it happens,
>   ISN'T IMPLEMENTED in the mos7720 driver!

http://advogato.org/person/tripp/diary/18.html